# Plotting Time Series with 8 variables

Tags: r, time, series

My dataframe looks like this

> ```
>      " States X2010 X2011 X2012 X2013 X2014 X2015 X2016 Andhra pradhesh   116    99  2827  4827  1359   817   660 Arunachal pradhesh     0     0     0     0     0    35   Assam     0     0     0   742     0     0    38
> ```

How can I plot in ggplot. I tried all posted answers here. My problem is that I dont know how to handle years when it comes as column names. X2010 X2011 X2012 X2013 X2014 X2015 X2016.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty tough to discern with the data that you've posted, but I'll take a shot at it anyways. The biggest problem you have in plotting time series data is that your data is in wide format, rather than long. If you convert it to long, it will be much easier to do. I wrote up a quick example using the `tidyr` package, and some random sample data that fits what I think the structure of your data is looking like (although, in the future, formatting goes a long ways in questions.) Step through this example and see if something like this would suit your question.

```
set.seed(100)
df <- data.frame(States = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j'),
                 X2010 = runif(10),
                 X2011 = runif(10),
                 X2012 = runif(10),
                 X2013 = runif(10),
                 X2014 = runif(10),
                 X2015 = runif(10),
                 X2016 = runif(10))

library('tidyr')
library('ggplot2')
library('stringr')

df <- gather(df, year, value, X2010:X2016)
df$year <- str_replace_all(df$year, 'X', '')
df$year <- as.numeric(df$year)

ggplot(df, aes(x = year, y = value, group = States, color = States)) + geom_line()
```

After gathering the wide data to long format, you'll have a unique row for each state and year. Again, I can't really tell for sure if this is what your data is looking like, but given your header, I'm fairly certain that reshaping your data will go a long way to plotting a time series. If this doesn't work, be sure to edit your question to be more specific and include better formatting of your sample data.

Comment: The solution suggested by you worked. Also I formatted the data in long format and used melt function from reshape2.                                                    > df.long<- melt(df, id.vars ="Years", measure.vars  =  c('Andhra.pradhesh', 'Arunachal.pradhesh', 'Assam','Puduchery'))
>  ggplot(df.long, aes(Years, value, colour = variable)) + geom_line()